# My dwellers keep getting injured, even when they're not going out

Tags: fallout-shelter

My dwellers keep getting injured and I'm not sure why. I thought it was radiation, so I checked and nobody in the whole vault has it. Even if I heal them, their health goes down without even being attacked. I tried to fix it by using Stimpacks, but I can't produce enough to heal everyone. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8):

This could be due to starvation, as in Fallout Shelter if you have no food all dwellers slowly take damage. Keep in mind that if there is no water, they will start to take *radiation* damage.

Hope this helps!

Comment: helped. It was propably due to starvation, as you said. Had some problems with food. Thank you.

Comment: @Alpinia423 If it helped, you might consider accepting the answer ;-)